# Two video players appear in UIWebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Why when I play the video, there are two overlapping video players. Can someone tell me why and how to solve it?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let mediaURL:URL = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/") {
            let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: mediaURL)
            webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.webview.loadRequest(request)
            }
        }
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {

    }
}
```

[This is the video image I took](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ7pu.jpg)

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: yes I show code . can you help me!